# How to retrieve dictionary from Firebase ? ( Xcode 10, Swift )

Tags: swift, firebase

I have a Firebase database which looks like this :

This is for a game server that sends a dictionary of the scores of the different players to be able to compare them.

```
results: {
   users: {
      user1: [
         {score}
      ]
      user2: [
         {score}
      ]
      user3: [
         {score}
      ]
       . . .

   }
}
```

Please what is the best way to retrieve these scores and put them in a dictionary ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this structure

```
results
   users
     user1 - score
     user2 - score
```

To set

```
dbRef = Database.database().reference() 
let con:[String:Any] = ["user1":5,"user2":6]
dbRef.child("results/users").setValue(con)
```

To listen

```
dbRef.child("results/users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    if let res = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
         print(res)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works perfectly ! I have another question: how can I add data to my database (= dictionary) without the new data replacing old ones? Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Thomas If this answer helped, be sure to accept it so it can help others.

Comment: Of course, sorry and thank you.